# How to rearrange this array

Tags: php, arrays, transformation

I have one question about PHP coding!

I want to send data to Google sheets, and all works well, I made an app!

I grab data from my app, and send data to sheets, but transferred data isn't sorted well.

The code is below:

```
foreach($processor->maildata As $data){
    if( in_array($data[_FF_DATA_TITLE].$data[_FF_DATA_ID], $bffields) ){
        $rowData[] = [$data[_FF_DATA_VALUE]];
    }
}
```

I getting data as `$rowData[]=[["test"],["test"],["test"]]` but they should be sortet as `$rowData[]=[["test","test","test"]]`.

I always get data in sheets one below the other in A1 row, but they should be sorted in sheets row by row (A,B,C..)

I hope I explained it well!
Any help!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

By using the `[]` around the `$data[_FF_DATA_VALUE]` you are actually telling PHP to add the value from the data array into a *new* array.

If you want:

- $rowData to contain one array (the row)
- and this array to contain the values (e.g. `test`)

.. you should simply omit the `[]` around the data array like this:

```
foreach($processor->maildata As $data){
    if( in_array($data[_FF_DATA_TITLE].$data[_FF_DATA_ID], $bffields) ){
        $rowData[] = $data[_FF_DATA_VALUE];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @thephper, I found a solution for my problem, thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the soluction is:

```
foreach($processor->maildata As $data){
              if( in_array($data[_FF_DATA_TITLE].$data[_FF_DATA_ID], $bffields) ){

              $rowData[]=$data[_FF_DATA_VALUE];
            
              }
            
            }

$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => [$rowData]]);

           $params =['valueInputOption' => 'RAW'];
           $insert=["valueDataOption" => "INSERT_RAW"];
           $this->response = $this->service->spreadsheets_values->append($gdata->spreadsheet_id, $range, $requestBody, $params,  $insert);
```

In this part of code:

before:

```
  $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => $rowData]);
```

now:

```
      $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => [$rowData]]);
```

I wrapped "$rowData" with brackets "[]" and it is it!

I got the desired solution, and the data was properly sorted on the sheet!